# Amazon AWS cost of small basic web

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need a place to host a small basic static web site made up of a bunch of file and folders (html, css, images, etc.) for a non-profit.  I've looked at Amazon AWS a bit and it looks like it could be done for a very small cost.

Is it really possible to host a web site At Amazon AWS for under a $1.00/month?

Is there any way to use the free AWS and then determine what the cost would have been if one used the paid option?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming/coding question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it really possible to host a web site At Amazon AWS for under a
>   $1.00/month?

If you just have static files, then you can definitely host the site on S3 for a very low price. If you have a dynamic website (PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, etc.) then you will need an actual server to run that on, and it will be more like $5 a month minimum.

Note that you will pay for data transfer, so if your site gets very popular the price could start to go up.

> Is there any way to use the free AWS and then determine what the cost
>   would have been if one used the paid option?

You can [enable detailed billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html) on the AWS account. Then you could punch those numbers into the [AWS cost calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) to see what the charges would have been if you were not in your free tier period.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it really possible to host a web site At Amazon AWS for under a
>   $1.00/month?

It is possible for 1$/Month in AWS  but your usage and traffic has to be less. Free tier is available but it is available for one year only and following are the resources available in free tier https://aws.amazon.com/free/.

You can also refer this which gives approximation. http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/aws-s3-pricing/

> Is there any way to use the free AWS and then determine what the cost
>   would have been if one used the paid option?

You can calculate this cost at https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Also you stated in your question it is non-profit. So AWS provides $2000 credits for non-profits.

https://aws.amazon.com/government-education/nonprofits/

Comment: If it's a static website hosted on S3, and receives very little traffic, and you aren't using any other services like Route53 or CloudFront, then it could definitely stay under $1 a month.

Comment: Be aware the $2000 credir for non-profits comes with a $175 admin fee.